# Best way to compute multiple data.frame columns from patterns

Tags: r, dataframe

I regularly receive data as a `data.frame` in wide format like the following:

```
head(data)
         date       NSW_1       AUS_1        NSW_2      AUS_2
1  2000-01-01 -0.38358623 -1.78824221  0.995984590  1.0744594
2  2001-01-01 -1.95910318  2.03124252 -1.695764903  0.2605978
3  2002-01-01 -0.84170506 -0.70314433 -0.533372143 -0.3142720
4  2003-01-01  1.90354747  0.15816476 -1.372269451 -0.7496301
5  2004-01-01  0.62249393  0.50623480 -2.207919779 -0.8621983
6  2005-01-01  1.99092044 -0.81999511  1.822122519  2.0480403
```

I need to compute several new columns from this data, for example:

```
NSW_3 = NSW_1 + NSW_2
AUS_3 = NSW_1 + AUS_2
NET_1 = NSW_1 + AUS_1 - AUS_2
...
```

Currently, the code to generate this uses Base R like this:

```
data$NSW_3 = df$NSW_1 + df$NSW_2
data$AUS_3 = data$NSW_1 + data$AUS_2
data$NET_1 = data$NSW_1 + data$AUS_1 - data$AUS_2
...
```

Doing this for a few columns is fine, using any available solution from `dplyr`, `data.table` or Base R. However, in reality my initial data is several thousand columns and hundreds of rows, and I need to create hundreds of new columns for tasks further down the pipeline.

Luckily, I have stored in a script the "patterns" for each column as text, for example `"NSW_3 = NSW_1 + NSW_2"` (and in any case, it is easy enough to get ChatGPT to convert the code into this). One question is whether the above style repeating `df$` is indeed the best option.

**Q: What is the best way to compute multiple new columns based off this list of patterns?**

Note that I am somewhat locked into this workflow due to dependencies further down the pipeline which are costly to change, so I am looking for a clean/best practice solution to this problem as given. The solution should ideally have the property that it is easy to update/change the patterns over time.

One constraint in this procedure is that there is no *pattern* to the patterns - the column construction is pretty arbitrary because it comes from  (in my situation) varying accounting standards.

---

Example data

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(10957, 11323, 11688, 12053, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13514, 13879, 14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 
15706, 16071, 16436, 16801, 17167, 17532, 17897), class = "Date"), 
    NSW_1 = c(1.24119982707737, 0.138858419103515, 1.71063158823657, 
    -0.430640974722993, -1.04422958092706, 0.537579524580529, 
    -0.669585987150229, 0.638805611438309, -1.72398983449257, 
    -1.74243008034091, 0.689804173282994, 0.330963177173467, 
    0.871067708948055, -2.01624558221344, 1.21257910351036, 1.20049469882194, 
    1.03206832593544, 0.786410256177216, 2.11007351377927, -1.45380984681329
    ), AUS_1 = c(-0.58310384813065, 0.409723982550305, -0.806981635414238, 
    0.0855504408545073, 0.746243168639741, -0.653673061331084, 
    0.657105983301959, 0.549909235009709, -0.806729358432671, 
    -0.997379717276235, 0.97589063842626, -0.169423180700716, 
    0.72219177943747, -0.844418606912503, 1.27729368500115, -1.34311054918022, 
    0.765340668860696, 0.464202569980373, 0.267993278040529, 
    0.667522687135242), NSW_2 = c(0.398467283863779, -0.638071030930068, 
    -0.267712904023511, 0.359879564885712, -1.31286609394071, 
    -0.883969609668706, 2.07709479458465, -2.09922563220098, 
    -1.23850596532828, 0.990433089664036, 1.08866186319808, 0.839852254188259, 
    0.0568586386833875, 0.32387805118027, -0.904668667590953, 
    -0.65218384837012, -0.262454637960949, -0.934662840905703, 
    0.821161212634175, -1.62425917345994), AUS_2 = c(-1.03040366948029, 
    -1.261929311973, 0.39218462589648, -1.13143826165372, 0.544144484008162, 
    1.17660893473457, 0.0252285692390373, 0.515133169692034, 
    -0.654109760017422, 0.503641990827566, -1.2721192223284, 
    -0.0767711536986575, -1.34531937567941, -0.266317560246187, 
    1.08756299501947, 0.700567795415207, -0.4427595146404, -0.78851996588786, 
    -0.856775709774438, -0.746419014623393)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: Are you hoping to *generalize* patterns? Your first two calculations make me think *"for any pair of columns of the form `XXX_1` and `XXX_2`, create `XXX_3 = XXX_1 + XXX_2`"*. But then the `NET_1` calculation is different. If you want to convert text that is slightly simpler than code to code, then r2evans's solution is good. But if you want to generalize a pattern to multiple matching columns, that could happen too.

Comment: @GregorThomas Good point, I meant to include this in the question and will edit. There is no pattern to the column construction (annoyingly!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the commands are held in a character vector `cmds` as shown in (1) below.  If they are in a text file we could create `cmds` like this.

```
cmds <- readLines("cmds.txt")
```

Then we have some alternatives.

**1) Reduce** Use `Reduce` with a function that runs str2lang/eval.  Note that `Reduce` will run the commands in order so that it would be possible for a command to use variables created in prior commands.

No packages are used.

```
cmds <- c("NSW_3 = NSW_1 + NSW_2",
          "AUS_3 = NSW_1 + AUS_2",
          "NET_1 = NSW_1 + AUS_1 - AUS_2")

Eval <- function(data, x) within(data, eval(str2lang(x)))
data1 <- Reduce(Eval, cmds, data)
```

**2) for** This would also work:

```
data2 <- data
for(cmd in cmds) data2 <- Eval(data2, cmd)
```

**3) single within** Another approach is to generate the text of a single `within` statement and parse and execute it.  Omit the `rev` if commands can depend on prior commands but if this is done then the columns won't be in the same order as (1) and (2).

```
data3 <- paste("within(data, {", paste(rev(cmds), collapse = "\n"), "})") |>
  str2lang() |>
  eval()
```

**4) source** If the commands are in a file `cmds.txt` then we can simply `source` them into an environment holding the columns of data.  This may cause the resulting columns to be in a different order than the prior alternatives.

```
source("cmds.txt", local = e <- list2env(data))
data4 <- modifyList(data, as.list(e))
```

Comment: Nice, esp the use of `str2lang` and `within`, and wow, the use of `Reduce` allows _building_ of expressions. Very slick.

Comment: Thanks, these are pretty handy.

Answer (score 3):

If you have *named* strings of your expressions, you can `eval(parse(..))` them fairly directly.

```r
exprs <- c(NSW_3 = "NSW_1 + NSW_2", AUS_3 = "NSW_1 + AUS_2", NET_1 = "NSW_1 + AUS_1 - AUS_2")
quux[names(exprs)] <- lapply(exprs, function(expr) eval(parse(text = expr), envir = quux))
quux
#          date      NSW_1       AUS_1       NSW_2       AUS_2       NSW_3       AUS_3       NET_1
# 1  2000-01-01  1.2411998 -0.58310385  0.39846728 -1.03040367  1.63966711  0.21079616  1.68849965
# 2  2001-01-01  0.1388584  0.40972398 -0.63807103 -1.26192931 -0.49921261 -1.12307089  1.81051171
# 3  2002-01-01  1.7106316 -0.80698164 -0.26771290  0.39218463  1.44291868  2.10281621  0.51146533
# 4  2003-01-01 -0.4306410  0.08555044  0.35987956 -1.13143826 -0.07076141 -1.56207924  0.78634773
# 5  2004-01-01 -1.0442296  0.74624317 -1.31286609  0.54414448 -2.35709567 -0.50008510 -0.84213090
# 6  2005-01-01  0.5375795 -0.65367306 -0.88396961  1.17660893 -0.34639009  1.71418846 -1.29270247
# 7  2006-01-01 -0.6695860  0.65710598  2.07709479  0.02522857  1.40750881 -0.64435742 -0.03770857
# 8  2007-01-01  0.6388056  0.54990924 -2.09922563  0.51513317 -1.46042002  1.15393878  0.67358168
# 9  2008-01-01 -1.7239898 -0.80672936 -1.23850597 -0.65410976 -2.96249580 -2.37809959 -1.87660943
# 10 2009-01-01 -1.7424301 -0.99737972  0.99043309  0.50364199 -0.75199699 -1.23878809 -3.24345179
# 11 2010-01-01  0.6898042  0.97589064  1.08866186 -1.27211922  1.77846604 -0.58231505  2.93781403
# 12 2011-01-01  0.3309632 -0.16942318  0.83985225 -0.07677115  1.17081543  0.25419202  0.23831115
# 13 2012-01-01  0.8710677  0.72219178  0.05685864 -1.34531938  0.92792635 -0.47425167  2.93857886
# 14 2013-01-01 -2.0162456 -0.84441861  0.32387805 -0.26631756 -1.69236753 -2.28256314 -2.59434663
# 15 2014-01-01  1.2125791  1.27729369 -0.90466867  1.08756300  0.30791044  2.30014210  1.40230979
# 16 2015-01-01  1.2004947 -1.34311055 -0.65218385  0.70056780  0.54831085  1.90106249 -0.84318365
# 17 2016-01-01  1.0320683  0.76534067 -0.26245464 -0.44275951  0.76961369  0.58930881  2.24016851
# 18 2017-01-01  0.7864103  0.46420257 -0.93466284 -0.78851997 -0.14825258 -0.00210971  2.03913279
# 19 2018-01-01  2.1100735  0.26799328  0.82116121 -0.85677571  2.93123473  1.25329780  3.23484250
# 20 2019-01-01 -1.4538098  0.66752269 -1.62425917 -0.74641901 -3.07806902 -2.20022886 -0.03986815
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(date = structure(c(10957, 11323, 11688, 12053, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13514, 13879, 14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 15706, 16071, 16436, 16801, 17167, 17532, 17897), class = "Date"), NSW_1 = c(1.24119982707737, 0.138858419103515, 1.71063158823657, -0.430640974722993, -1.04422958092706, 0.537579524580529, -0.669585987150229, 0.638805611438309, -1.72398983449257, -1.74243008034091, 0.689804173282994, 0.330963177173467, 0.871067708948055, -2.01624558221344, 1.21257910351036, 1.20049469882194,  1.03206832593544, 0.786410256177216, 2.11007351377927, -1.45380984681329), AUS_1 = c(-0.58310384813065, 0.409723982550305, -0.806981635414238, 0.0855504408545073, 0.746243168639741, -0.653673061331084, 0.657105983301959, 0.549909235009709, -0.806729358432671, -0.997379717276235, 0.97589063842626, -0.169423180700716, 0.72219177943747, -0.844418606912503, 1.27729368500115, -1.34311054918022, 0.765340668860696, 0.464202569980373, 0.267993278040529, 0.667522687135242), NSW_2 = c(0.398467283863779, -0.638071030930068,  -0.267712904023511, 0.359879564885712, -1.31286609394071, -0.883969609668706, 2.07709479458465, -2.09922563220098, -1.23850596532828, 0.990433089664036, 1.08866186319808, 0.839852254188259, 0.0568586386833875, 0.32387805118027, -0.904668667590953, -0.65218384837012, -0.262454637960949, -0.934662840905703, 0.821161212634175, -1.62425917345994), AUS_2 = c(-1.03040366948029, -1.261929311973, 0.39218462589648, -1.13143826165372, 0.544144484008162, 1.17660893473457, 0.0252285692390373, 0.515133169692034,  -0.654109760017422, 0.503641990827566, -1.2721192223284, -0.0767711536986575, -1.34531937567941, -0.266317560246187, 1.08756299501947, 0.700567795415207, -0.4427595146404, -0.78851996588786, -0.856775709774438, -0.746419014623393)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: This is cool and the kind of approach I suspected. What do you reckon about the robustness/speed of this route?

Comment: Unless you want a _heuristic_ to determine which columns to add, which to subtract ... I don't think anything non-compiled will be able to do any better; most meta-methods (such as `rlang` and `!!`/`quos`/... tidy methods) have just a little bit more overhead (barely noticeable, usually).

Comment: (1) I just edited it, made it a little more efficient by removing `with`. (2) To be fair, I make the statement of "nothing faster" not out of hubris or expectation of my own awesomeness ... it's because of where the overhead here is located: parsing the strings into expressions, and evaluating them in the context of the data. I know of no other way to parse a string into something that be executed easily, and `eval` is as internal/fast/efficient as one can get in R.