# How to run a equation on columns of multiple .txt files and save output in new columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr, lapply

I have various .txt files stored in different folders. The .txt file structure is given below. ABC, DEF and MNO are columns already present in txt files (but not all three columns are present in each txt file). I want to apply following equations on all the .txt files and save the output in new columns, for say, ABC_new, DEF_new, MNO_new

```
ABC_new = 1.5*SA*u^1.1 + 700
DEF_new = SA*u^2.5
MNO_new = 1.8*SA*u^1.5 + 40
```

Structure of txt file is as follows. (Every two columns are seperated by a tab in actual txt files)

```
D_T  SA  u  ABC  DEF  MNO  ...
2021-03-01W00:01:00+00  118  12  112  134  145  ...
2021-03-01W00:02:00+00  112  11  111  134  146  ...
2021-03-01W00:03:00+00  111  14  110  135  156  ...
..
..
```

Each .txt file has different number of lines to skip, hence, it needs to be read in following way. Also, I have tried to write a code till a certain point. Could anyone please help me in elaborating the code to achieve the desired goal.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dirlist <- list.files(full.names = FALSE, no.. = TRUE) 
dirlist

read_the_files <- function(filelist){
  lapply(filelist, function(file) {
    fread(file, skip = "D/T\tXY [XY]")    #to read from the line next to fragment D/T XY [XY]
  })
}

adjust_column_names <- function(dt_list){
  lapply(dt_list, FUN = function(x){

    if ("ABC" %in% colnames(x)) {
      x[ABC_new = 1.5 X SA X u^1.1 + 700]
    }

    if ("DEF" %in% colnames(x)) {
      x[DEF_new = SA X u^2.5]
    }

    if ("MNO" %in% colnames(x)) {
      x[MNO_new = 1.8 X SA X u^1.5 + 40]
    }

    return(x)
  })
}

for (idx in seq_along(dirlist)){
  filelist <- list.files(path = dirlist[idx], full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = 
                       ".txt$")
  dt1_ <- read_the_files(filelist)
  dt1.tidied <- adjust_column_names(dt1_)
```

Desired output:

If input contains 3 txt files in Folder A, 2 txt files in Folder B...and so on, then in output also, there should be 3 txt files in Folder A, 2 txt files in Folder B...and so on. The file structure of txt file should be as follows:

```
D_T  SA  u  ABC  DEF  MNO  ABC_new  DEF_new  MNO_new...
2021-03-01W00:01:00+00  118  12  112  134  145  ...
2021-03-01W00:02:00+00  112  11  111  134  146  ...
2021-03-01W00:03:00+00  111  14  110  135  156  ...
..
..
```

output of dput of input

```
structure(list(`D_T` = c("2021-03-01T00:01:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:02:00", "2021-03-01T00:03:00", "2021-03-01T00:04:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:05:00", "2021-03-01T00:06:00", "2021-03-01T00:07:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:08:00", "2021-03-01T00:09:00", "2021-03-01T00:10:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:11:00", "2021-03-01T00:12:00", "2021-03-01T00:13:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:14:00", "2021-03-01T00:15:00", "2021-03-01T00:16:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:17:00", "2021-03-01T00:18:00", "2021-03-01T00:19:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:20:00", "2021-03-01T00:21:00", "2021-03-01T00:22:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:23:00", "2021-03-01T00:24:00", "2021-03-01T00:25:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:26:00", "2021-03-01T00:27:00", "2021-03-01T00:28:00", "2021-03- 
01T00:29:00", "2021-03-01T00:30:00"), `XY [XY]` = c(0.990641, 0.990641, 
0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 
0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 
0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 
0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641, 0.990641), 
`SA [sa]` = c(257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 
257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 
257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 257L, 
257L, 257L, 257L), `u [U]` = c(285L, 
285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 
285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 
285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L, 285L), 
`ABC [abc]` = c(255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 
255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 
255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 
255L, 255L, 255L), `DEF [def]` = c(0.463735, 0.463735, 
0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 
0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 
0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 
0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 
0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735, 0.463735), `MNO [mno]` = c(1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1013L), Lc = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Tried code after suggestion ([code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553080/best-way-to-compute-multiple-data-frame-columns-from-patterns)) by r2evans in the comments:

```
library(data.table)
rm(list = ls())
setwd("F:/Data")

files <- list.files(path = "F:/BSRN_txt", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = 
                  ".txt$")
readdata <- function(fn){
  dt_temp <- fread(fn, skip = "Date/Time\tAU [AU]")
}
mylist <- lapply(files, readdata)
mydata <- rbindlist( mylist,  fill = TRUE )

exprs <- c("ABC_new = 1.5 * SA * u^1.1 + 700", "DEF_new = SA * u^2.5", "MNO_new = 1.8 * SA * u^1.5 + 40")

Reduce(function(data, x) within(data, eval(str2lang(x))), init = mydata)
```

This gives me error:

```
Error in Reduce(function(data, x) within(data, eval(str2lang(x))), init = mydata) :   argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Kindly help in resolving the error.

Comment: The structure of your df is unclear. what  are the columns that have `()` mean? edit your question this time round using `|` as the delimiter and create a table

Comment: check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support 
 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support on how to creat a markdown table in stackoverflow

Comment: ( ) contain the units of each column entity. Anyways I have removed them from the question now to simplify.

Comment: You say every two column are separated by tab. what about in between the two columns? Is the delimiter a space?

Comment: Also, are you able to read the files into R?? Is the question about reading the files AND transforming them or just transforming the resulting dataframe of the files that have been read into R?

Comment: You mentioned that each file needs to skip a different number of rows. If you have this figured out, then we don't need it in the question. If you don't have this part figured out, then we cannot help unless we know what they look like. Previous comments have suggested you include _data_ in your question, I would like to instead request the top `n` lines (especially lines to be skipped!) from at least 2-3 representative files so that we can try to deduce a pattern for smartly skipping lines.

Comment: Alexia you can't just post the same question twice

Comment: @Onyambu The delimiter is the tab. Yes, I am able to read the files and am confident that the steps till read_the_files are working fine (because I have used the same code lines for another purpose). I need help beyond that in two things: (1) I want to confirm what I did in 'adjust_col_names', is it correct? (2) How to get desired output files? I tried to use 'for' loop but it is incomplete.

Comment: @Mark I have simplified the question in this post and hence, deleted the other one, also because it does not contain any answers.

Comment: If you have read the files into R, then consider giving the data as it appears in R rather than in the text files.

Comment: @r2evans I am able to skip the different number of rows using 'read_the_files' code and it is working properly (I know this because I have used the same code lines for another purpose). I need help beyond that in two things: (1) I want to confirm what I did in 'adjust_col_names', is it correct? (2) How to get desired output files? I tried to use 'for' loop but it is incomplete. Do you still need data in question?

Comment: @Onyambu Could you please tell me how I can do that? I mean which command to use? Sorry I am beginner.

Comment: copy paste the a few lines of the data that is in R. eg `head(data, 3)`. Or you could use `dput` function

Comment: @Onyambu Added output of dput of input. Kindly check

Comment: and what exactly is `1.5 X SA X u^1.1 + 700`?? what is `u`? `X`? `SA`?? in the provided data, there are only `SA [sa]` `U [u]` columns. there is no `X` column. and your code `1.5 X SA X u^1.1 + 700` does not make sense

Comment: @Onyambu X is the sign of multiplication. It is 1.5*SA*u^1.1 + 700

Comment: Why does your sample data have names `"ABC"`, `"DEF"`, and `"MNO"`) and your `dput` output has names like `"ABC [abc]"`, `"DEF [def]"`, `"MNO [mno]"`? Are we supposed to find a way to map between the different names?

Comment: This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76553080/3358272. With `exprs <- c("ABC_new = 1.5 X SA X u^1.1 + 700", "DEF_new = SA X u^2.5", "MNO_new = 1.8 X SA X u^1.5 + 40")` and `quux` as your _first_ sample data, this works: `Reduce(function(data, x) within(data, eval(str2lang(x))), gsub("\\bX\\b", "*", exprs), init = quux)`

Comment: @r2evans Initially, in the post, I have written column names as ABC (abc), DEF (def) and so on, where ( ) represents units. As another user was getting confused with brackets, I removed them from sample data to simplify, but I think it is creating confusion.

Comment: I see, thank you. Your question of how to automate several expressions (you listed three) on data that is read from many files seems to be resolved using the code from my previous question. Can you confirm? The linked answer has a couple of related ways to do the same thing, I think you can choose one that resonates well with your coding style.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you, I tried it but it is giving me an error. I have copied pasted the tried code and error in the post. Could you please help.

Comment: @r2evans I am not sure if the error could also be due to the varying number of initial rows in all the txt files, that need to be skipped. Could you please tell me how I can skip different number of rows in the suggested code?

Comment: @r2evans For your information, the initial rows, that need to skip, contain metadata about the columns. Though all files have different number of initial rows, one thing common in all the files is that the data starts from the line next to D/T\tXY [XY].

Comment: Ok. Does the code in my comment work for you?

Comment: @r2evans I tried that code but it is not working. That only is giving me the error mentioned in the post. Also, I need output for all the txt files in one log file.

Comment: (1) You changed your expressions from using `X` to using `*`, you no longer need the `gsub` workaround. (2) `quux` for me is the `data.frame` read in by whatever process you are using. When I said "first sample data", I meant _data_, not a vector of filenames. You said you already solved the "different number of lines to skip" problem, so I'm assuming you already have the data in-memory.

Comment: @r2evans   'X' is the sign of multiplication, so in code, I changed it to '*' . I solved different number of lines to skip' problem using 'read_the_lines' function in my code (shown in the post). If I read all my txt files as dataframe, then how to apply read_the_lines function because in your code, I need to input dataframe. Could you please help in this.

Comment: I thought that's what I've been doing. You say you know how to read in each file (using your function) in a way that solves your "different number of lines" issue. Once you read on _one_ file, apply my logic to _that one dataframe_. Once you've done that, then that one frame has the new columns. I think after that you would need to write the data back to disk, either to a new file or overwriting the original file (assuming you have a safe backup).

Comment: @r2evans Hi, I am able to read the files and I applied your suggested code but it is giving an error. Kindly refer to the post for details. Could you please help me in resolving the error.

Comment: You dropped the use of `exprs` from my code in your call to `Reduce`. The error message mentions `x`, which if you look at the help for `?Reduce`, you'll see how the function (first arg), `x=`, and `init=` work together. (I previously said you don't need the `gsub` *workaround*, but you still need `exprs`, how else can you get the expressions in to `str2lang`?)